# Perl hash, array and references

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I have this 3 lines of code in a sub and I'm trying to write them together on one line only.. but I'm quite lost

```
    my %p = @_;
    my $arr = $p{name};
    my @a = @$arr;
```

what's the correct way of doing this?

thank you!

Comment: `my %p = @_; my $arr = $p{name}; my @a = @$arr;` :P

Comment: Most would skip doing `my @a = @$arr;` as a needless waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my %p = @_;
```

`@_` is assumed to contain key-value pairs which are then used to construct the hash `%p`.

```
my $arr = $p{name};
```

The argument list is assumed to have contained something along the lines of `name, [1, 2, 3,]` so that `$p{name}` is an reference to an array.

```
my @a = @$arr;
```

Dereference that array reference to get the array `@`.

Here is an invocation that might work with this prelude in a `sub`:

```
func(this => 'that', name => [1, 2, 3]);
```

If you want to reduce the whole prelude to a single statement, you can use:

```
my @a = @{ { @_ }->{name} };
```

as in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML::XS;

func(this => 'that', name => [1, 2, 3]);

sub func {
    my @a = @{ { @_ }->{name} };
    print Dump \@a;
}
```

Output:

```
---
- 1
- 2
- 3
```

If the array pointed to by `name` is large, and if you do *not* need a shallow copy, however, it may be better to just stick with references:

```
my $aref = { @_ }->{ name };
```

Comment: Right, turning it into a reference works. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

OK so what you're doing is:

- Assign a list of elements passed to the sub, to a hash.
- extract a value from that hash (that appears to be an array reference)
- dereference *that* into a standalone array.

Now, I'm going to have to make some guesses as to what you're putting *in*:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

sub test {
    my %p = @_;
    my $arr = $p{name};
    my @a = @$arr;
    print Dumper \@a; 
}

my %input = ( fish => [ "value", "another value" ],
              name => [ "more", "less" ], );

test ( %input );
```

So with that in mind:

```
sub test {
    print join "\n", @{{@_}->{name}},"\n";
}
```

But actually, I'd suggest what you *probably* want to do is pass in the hashref in the first place:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

sub test {
    my ( $input_hashref ) = @_;
    print Dumper \@{$input_hashref -> {name}};
}

my %input = ( fish => [ "value", "another value" ],
              name => [ "more", "less" ], );
test ( \%input );
```

Also:

- Don't use single letter variable names. It's bad style.
- that goes double for `a` and `b` because `$a` and `$b` are for sorting. (And using `@a` is confusing as a result).